# Citus integration on android

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I am integrating a payment gateway called CITRUSPAY.

Wrote this code  :

```
    CitrusClient citrusClient = CitrusClient.getInstance(Context);
    citrusClient.init(
              "test-signup", 
              "c78ec84e389814a05d3ae46546d16d2e", 
              "test-signin", 
              "52f7e15efd4208cf5345dd554443fd99", 
              "testing", 
              Environment.SANDBOX ); 
CitrusClient citrusClient = CitrusClient.getInstance(context); // Activity Context
  // No need to call init on CitrusClient if already done.

  DebitCardOption debitCardOption = new DebitCardOption("Card Holder Name", "4111111111111111", "123", Month.getMonth("12"), Year.getYear("18"));

  Amount amount = new Amount("5");
  // Init PaymentType     
  PaymentType.PGPayment pgPayment = new PaymentType.PGPayment(amount, BILL_URL, debitCardOption, new CitrusUser("developercitrus@gmail.com","9876543210"));

  citrusClient.simpliPay(pgPayment, new Callback<TransactionResponse>() {

     @Override
     public void success(TransactionResponse transactionResponse) { }

     @Override
     public void error(CitrusError error) { }
  });
```

The problem i have is that i am getting this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://sandbox.citruspay.com/test?amount=5.0
OOPS! Something Went Wrong!
08-12 17:19:36.763 32273-32273/com.app.citruspayintegration D/CITRUSSDK: ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
08-12 17:19:36.763 32273-32273/com.app.citruspayintegration D/CITRUSSDK: ║ CitrusActivity$15.success  (CitrusActivity.java:886)
08-12 17:19:36.763 32273-32273/com.app.citruspayintegration D/CITRUSSDK: ║    CitrusActivity$15.success  (CitrusActivity.java:892)
08-12 17:19:36.763 32273-32273/com.app.citruspayintegration D/CITRUSSDK: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
08-12 17:19:36.763 32273-32273/com.app.citruspayintegration D/CITRUSSDK: ║ netbankForOTP : HDFC
08-12 17:19:36.763 32273-32273/com.app.citruspayintegration D/CITRUSSDK: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

If anyone has any idea then can help me.